# Android How obtain the folder list that contain images?

Tags: android, image, grid, directory

I want to realize an image gallery. In main view I want to view the image folder list. On click on grid item should open the grid with images of relative folder

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code, I hope it can be useful:

```
    // Get directory where camera images are stored
    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    File imageDir = null;
    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state) || Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(state)) {
        File externalDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        imageDir = new File(externalDir, "DCIM/camera");
        if (!imageDir.exists())
            /* Handle error */;
    }

    // List filenames of images
    String[] fileNames = imageDir.list();
```